# How to fix a Zabbix Trigger that always returns EOF

Tags: ubuntu, triggers, zabbix

I am having a problem configuring a Zabbix template Item/Trigger. I am trying to setup a trigger to check the HTTP status of a webpage. However, I seem to be having some difficulties as it always returns an error with "EOF".

I read the documentation that the [web.page.regexp](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/doku.php?id=1.8/manual/config/items) will return EOF if there is an error. I know that the host for the regexp works because I "curl"ed it from the host.

Below is my Item key:

```
web.page.regexp[127.0.0.1,,9198,HTTP/1\.1.*,12]
```

Here is my trigger:

```
(({Tungsten Check:web.page.regexp[127.0.0.1,,9198,HTTP/1\.1.*,12].regexp(HTTP/1.1\ 200)})#1)
```

Does anyone see anything blatantly wrong? I am following the instructions from the following tutorial: [HTTP Return Code Monitoring Without Web Monitoring](http://blog.kdecherf.com/2012/12/03/zabbix-http-return-code-monitoring-without-web-monitoring/)

I am not sure if I compiled Zabbix with CURL or not, could that be the reason?

**UPDATE #1**

I recompiled Zabbix with CURL support and it did not fix the issue, still getting the EOF message.

Comment: Isn't "HTTP/1\.1." a part of status response that is not being parsed since it is not a part of the "page" and not even the headers? curling it maybe different from what zabbix does even using libcurl.

Comment: Why don't you want to use web checks? This is what they are for.

Answer (score 0):

The following works on my instance:

`zabbix_get -s localhost -k web.page.regexp[www.bbc.co.uk,,80,HTTP/1\.1.*,12]`

and returns

`HTTP/1.1 200`

I think you get that error when it tries to select the first 12 characters of nothing. I could generate that error by either requesting from a host / port that wasn't valid, or the regexp didn't match anything.

Seeing as I've used your regexp which works, I would guess that you're either not receiving anything from your web server or it's not returning a line that matches your regexp - maybe HTTP 1.0?

I would recommend using proper web checks, even if it's just for one check. Would make it a little easier.

Hope this helps.

Will